# How to add System.Data.dll in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dllimport

I've added **System.Data.dll** to my *Assets\Plugins* folder. But when use using `System.Data` in scripts it says "The type or namespace 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System'..... ". In Viusal Studio it is not showing error

Comment: Well you are right. I know the answer but have already answered that. See the duplicated question.

Comment: OMG ..YOU ARE GREAT !! THANK YOU